# Android how to store /save data to Excel file or to Cvs file

Tags: java, android

I am devoloping new app to take some information from user like his name , his jop, his age ..etc ...I Want thw code To store or export or save this data to Excel file or to Cvs file ..

Thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

A CSV file is just a text file, so it's a lot easier to write to than an Excel file. For example:

```
// get a Uri to write to first

// Some made up data to write
StringBuilder d = new StringBuilder();
d.append("col1,col2,col3\n");
d.append("1,2,3\n");
d.append("2,3,4\n");
String data = d.toString();

// Get a file output stream however is compatible with your app. Showing one of
// many ways here.
// once you have it, call outputStream.write(data.getBytes());
try {
    ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "w");
    if (pfd != null) {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
        fileOutputStream.write(data.getBytes());
        fileOutputStream.close();
        pfd.close();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Sorry .. I am new at android programming ..where can i put this code ?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I am new at android programming.. where can I put this code..

Thanks

Comment: You have not provided nearly enough context to answer that. Have you started writing this app? If so, do you have a button or something the user would press to save the data? Places the user would enter the data you are trying to save?You'll have to edit your question with some more specifics (e.g. some code that says "here's where I want to save a file") to get a more specific answer